# How do I center these three blocks horizontally?

Tags: css

I'm trying to center three linked images horizontally. Below is what I've tried so far. I got the images aligned horizontally, but I can't figure out how to move all three to the center.

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <a href="/Chef">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/tWpiPid.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <a href="/Tactical">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KQPmsBn.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="wrapper1">
      <a href="/Tools">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XNpJVu1.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { background:#000 }
a { display:block }
img { width:150px }
.wrapper2 { float:left }
.outer-wrapper { text-align:center }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3hw11mgs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first remove `float:left`

Then  use `display:inline-block`and `margin:auto`

```
   .wrapper2 { 
      display:inline-block;
      margin:auto
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3hw11mgs/1/

Answer (score 4):

A great case of use for Flexbox here, just add this and it'll work:

```
.outer-wrapper { display:flex;justify-content:center; }
```

The best part is that you can even remove the `float:left;` from the `.wrapper2` and it'll work perfectly, so you are saving code too :)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3hw11mgs/3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `.wrapper2` and add `display:inline-block`

```
.wrapper2 { 
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3hw11mgs/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Or... You can remove `.wrapper2` completely its unneeded...
Here is a codepen for you... Using `display: flex;`

http://codepen.io/Ballard/pen/mAdvgx